# Pl/Sql Oracle Function in a procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to make a procedure that needs to update the situation of a student, but I need to use a function that returns 'A' for the approved students, and 'R' for the not approved. After this I need to update the field "Situation" with an 'A' or 'R' that is returned from the function. I already have the function, but I don't have any idea how to make the procedure. Here goes the code of the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_grade(grade     IN NUMBER,
                                       frequency IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
   RESULT VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT '';
BEGIN
   IF (grade >= 6) AND (frequency >= 0.75) THEN
      resultado := 'A';
   ELSE
      resultado := 'R';
   END IF;

   RETURN RESULT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating the things. You could do it in pure **SQL** rather than using **PL/SQL** function and  procedure.

You could use **CASE** expression, for example:

**Test 1**

```
SQL> SELECT
  2  CASE
  3      WHEN &grade   >=6
  4      AND &frequency>=0.75
  5      THEN 'A'
  6      ELSE 'R'
  7    END
  8    FROM DUAL;
Enter value for grade:   10
old   3:     WHEN &grade   >=6
new   3:     WHEN   10   >=6
Enter value for frequency: 1
old   4:     AND &frequency>=0.75
new   4:     AND 1>=0.75

C
-
A
```

**Test 2**

```
SQL> SELECT
  2  CASE
  3      WHEN &grade   >=6
  4      AND &frequency>=0.75
  5      THEN 'A'
  6      ELSE 'R'
  7    END
  8    FROM DUAL;
Enter value for grade:   1
old   3:     WHEN &grade   >=6
new   3:     WHEN   1   >=6
Enter value for frequency: 0.5
old   4:     AND &frequency>=0.75
new   4:     AND 0.5>=0.75

C
-
R
```

So, using the same logic in your **UPDATE** statement:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET situation = (
  CASE
    WHEN &grade   >=6
    AND &frequency>=0.75
    THEN 'A'
    ELSE 'R'
  END)
WHERE situation IS NOT NULL;
```

**Update** OP only wants to do it in a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure pr_update
 is
begin
update table_name 
   set Situation = check_grade(grade, frequency);
end;
/
```

In the above procedure, put actual table_name in the update statement. grade and frequency are considered as the column names of the table.

Comment: I have a new doubt. Now I need to create a trigger using this function. It's not working....

create or replace trigger situation
before 
insert on table_name
for each row
begin
select check_grade(grade, frequency)
into : new.situation
from dual;
end;

Comment: @RenenGeraldo, can you please open a new question regarding trigger.

Answer (score 0):

See if this help.

```
create or replace procedure pr_update(v_grade in number, v_frequency in number) is
update tab_name set Situation=check_grade(v_grade,v_frequency);
end;
```

Comment: I think it's almost this, but i need to select the values of grade and frequency in the table of students. How can I do this? And thanks